# Merge two geometries into one geometry from PLYLoaders

Tags: javascript, merge, three.js, ply-file-format

I have two PLY files, and I want to merged into one, but I have a problem with de loaders method of the PLYLoader, how i can access to the Geometry of the two loaders simultaneously?

I loaded the two ply files and I define new geometry (BufferGeometry class) for the new shape, but the variables `mesh1` and `mesh2` are undefined
when a I tried to access to the geometry properties.

Here is my code:

```
//  ...
var mesh1, material1;
var mesh2, material2;
var singleGeometry, material, mesh;
// ...

init();
animate();

singleGeometry = BufferGeometry();

function init() {
  //   ...
  singleGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  //  ...

  var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
  loader.load("path/ply1.ply", function(geometry) {
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x0055ff, flatShading: true });
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    mesh1.position.y = -0.2;
    mesh1.position.z = 0.3;
    mesh1.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    mesh1.scale.multiplyScalar(0.01);
    mesh1.castShadow = true;
    mesh1.receiveShadow = true;
  });
  loader.load("path/ply2.ply", function(geometry) {
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x0055ff, flatShading: true });
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    mesh2.position.x = -0.2;
    mesh2.position.y = -0.02;
    mesh2.position.z = -0.2;
    mesh2.scale.multiplyScalar(0.0006);
    mesh2.castShadow = true;
    mesh2.receiveShadow = true;
  });

  var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
  loader.load("ply/Paso_1_mandible.ply", function(geometry) {
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x0055ff, flatShading: true });
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    mesh1.position.y = -0.2;
    mesh1.position.z = 0.3;
    mesh1.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    mesh1.scale.multiplyScalar(0.01);
    mesh1.castShadow = true;
    mesh1.receiveShadow = true;
  });
  loader.load("ply/Lucy100k.ply", function(geometry) {
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x0055ff, flatShading: true });
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    mesh2.position.x = -0.2;
    mesh2.position.y = -0.02;
    mesh2.position.z = -0.2;
    mesh2.scale.multiplyScalar(0.0006);
    mesh2.castShadow = true;
    mesh2.receiveShadow = true;
  });
  singleGeometry.mergeBufferGeometries([mesh1.geometry, mesh2.geometry]);
  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're not waiting for the `loader` to have loaded the meshes `mesh1` and `mesh2` before you're attempting to merge them.

We can refactor this to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which makes dealing with the async loading a lot easier.

(I've removed the code that generated meshes from the single geometries, as that wasn't apparently used.)

```
var plyLoader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
function loadAsset(path) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    plyLoader.load(path, resolve);
  });
}

var singleGeometry, material, mesh;

Promise.all([
  loadAsset("ply/Paso_1_mandible.ply"),
  loadAsset("ply/Lucy100k.ply"),
])
  .then(geometries => {
    geometries.forEach(geometry => geometry.computeVertexNormals());
    var singleGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    singleGeometry.mergeBufferGeometries(geometries);
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
  })
  .then(() => {
    animate();
  });
```

Comment: this code should be inside the init function? because now i can't renderer

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't renderer"? Do you get an error? It doesn't matter where it is, but you should start rendering stuff only after everything is loaded, i.e. where there's an `animate()` call there now.

Comment: no, I didn't get any error and I tried to mean I can't see the the mesh in the scene or the browser

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the mesh or geometry that's generated, I think. You could add `console.log()`s to see whether the `geometries` objects and the `singleGeometry` object look correct.

Comment: I tried to print some element inside first `.then`, but nothing was shown, it's like never goes in there :(